# Usando .sort em Objeto Literal

Tags: javascript

Para não precisar ficar replicando o mesmo codigo em vários arquivos e até em mais de um lugar do mesmo arquivo, eu transformei a minha função que renderizava produtos no objeto literal abaixo:

```
produtoObj = function() {
    return {
        titulo: response.produto[i].dados.nome,
        preco: parseFloat(response.produto[i].dados.por),
        parcela: parseFloat(response.produto[i].dados.qtdParcela),
        valorParcela: parseFloat(response.produto[i].dados.por) / parseFloat(response.produto[0].dados.qtdParcela).toFixed(2),
        classe : response.produto[i].dados.id,
        imagem : produtos[i].dados.imgNome,
        renderiza: function () {
            var tagFig = "<piicture>" + "</piicture>";
            var tagPicture = $(tagFig).attr("class", "produtos-organizados a" + this.classe);
            var tagTituloProduto = "<figcaption>" + this.titulo + "</figcaption>";
            var tagPreco = "<p>" + "R$ " + this.preco + "</p>";
            var parcela = this.parcela;
            var converteTotal = this.valorParcela;
            var tagParcela = "<p>" + "at\u00e9 " + this.parcela + "x" + " de " + converteTotal + "</p>";
            var tagDiv = "<div>" + "</div>";
            var divP = $(tagDiv).append(tagPreco, tagParcela);

            var btnId = "<i class='large material-icons' id='response.produto[0].dados.id'>" + "shopping_cart" + "</i>";

            var test = "<img src='img/produtos/" + this.imagem + ".jpg' />";

            var teste = $('.produtos');

            var add1 = $(tagPicture).append(test, tagTituloProduto, divP, btnId);
            var add2 = $(teste).append(add1);

        }
    };
};
```

Mas depois que fiz isso comecei a ter problemas ao tanto ao tentar carregar mais produtos, quanto para utilizar o `.sort` em uma outra parte do código, e ao invés de renderizar os produtos normalmente ao chamar carregar mais produtos, e chamar o `renderizaData`, `renderizaMaiorPreco` ou `renderizaMenorPreco` (as funções que recebem o `.sort`) sempre é chamado os mesmos valores do meu `json`:

```
$(".add-produtos").on("click", function(){
    for(var i = 7; i < 9; i++) {
        var testar = produtoObj();
        testar.renderiza();
    };
    $('.carregar').removeClass("add-produtos"); //tentativa de limitar o numero de vezes que é possivel chamar a função de adicionar os produtos.
});
```

Acima o código que carrega mais produtos, e abaixo a que reorganiza os produtos:

```
function ordenarData() {
    $("#mais-recente").on("click", function(){
        remover();
        renderizaProdutoPorData();
    });

    function renderizaProdutoPorData(){
        var response = JSON.parse(produto.responseText);
        var produtos = response.produto;
        produtos.sort(compareData);

        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            var testar = produtoObj();
            testar.renderiza();
        }


        $(".carregar").on("click", function(){
            for(var i = 7; i< 10; i++) {
                var testar = produtoObj();
                testar.renderiza();
            };
        })
    }

    function remover(){
        $(".produtos-organizados").remove();
    };
};

function compareData(a, b) {
    return (a.dados.data) < (b.dados.data);
}
```

Comment: Você não está passando o `i` quando chama `produtoObj()`.

Comment: Eu testei trocar o 'i'

Comment: Eu disse passar, não trocar. Você usa o `i` dentro da função, precisa passar ele como argumento.

Answer (score 0):

Nossa gente eu falei que estava verificando minha resposta, aqui está:

```
var Array1 = [{
    item1: 'A',
    item3: 10
},{
    item1: 'B',
    item3: 19
},{
    item1: 'C',
    item3: 1
}];

var Objeto2 = {
    objeto1 : {
        item1: 'A',
        item3: 19
    },
    objeto2 : {
        item1: 'B',
        item3: 10
    }
};

Array1.sort(function(a,b){
    console.log('ARRAY a: ',a);
  console.log('ARRAY b: ',b);
  return a.item3 - b.item3; //CRESCENTE
  //return b.item3 - a.item3; //DECRESCENTE
});
console.log('sort em array com objetos: ',Array1);

/*
Objeto2.sort(); // isso vai trazer um erro
Objeto2.sort(function(a,b){ //isso vai trazer um erro
    console.log('OBJETO a: ',a);
  console.log('OBJETO b: ',b);
});*/

// Da para fazer isso:
var objKeys = Object.keys(Objeto2).sort(function(a,b){
   return Objeto2[a].item3 - Objeto2[b].item3;
});
console.log(keysObjeto); // AI TENDO AS KEYS DO OBJETO VC MANIPULA COM UM FOR USANDO ESSAS KEYS, OU CRIA UM NOVO OBJETO.

var NovoObjeto = {}; // ou array
for(var idx = 0; idx < keysObjeto.length; idx++){
   NovoObjeto[keysObjeto[idx]] = Objeto2[keysObjeto[idx]];
}

console.log('Objeto2 Antigo: ',Objeto2);
console.log('NovoObjeto: ',NovoObjeto);
```

Não sei se você viu a resposta anterior, mas o exemplo de Object.keys() pode ser visto no site MDN : [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)